# Dynamically create boxes using vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wanted to create square boxes dynamically, based on number of array entries using vue.js.

eg: An array with

> ['101','102','103']

are passed from browser console to `vue.js` script, then three square boxes with text `101` on the first box and so on should be created.

Comment: You wanted to do that, OK. Have you _tried_ to do that? What problems are you facing?

Comment: I tried to create boxes sending in an array and used v-for property. I tried to send the array ['101', '102'] from browser console to the vue script, so that no hard coded is used. I'm still figuring out

Answer (score 1):

To get you started and probably the better and easier method check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqo515xr/1/) by **@bert** posted in comment

you can also make use of [Render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) so that you get powers of javascript to programmatically build your html

**script**

```
Vue.component("my-boxes", {
    props: ["boxes"],
    render(createElement){
        
        return createElement("div",
            this.boxes.map((box) => {
              return createElement('div', {
                  style: {width: "50px", height: "50px", border: "1px solid red", margin: "5px"}
              }, box);
            })
        )
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data(){
        return{
            myArr: ["101", "102", "103"]
        }
    }
})
```

**template**

```
<div id="app">
    <my-boxes :boxes="myArr"></my-boxes>
</div>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k162qzm3/4/)

**Summary:**

- `render` function receives `createElement` as its argument.
- This `createElement` is used to create virtual nodes which vue puts together form a virtual dOM. This virtual DOM is then used to create the actual HTML DOM which gets rendered o the page.
- We pass a prop `boxes` to `my-boxes` component which contains the array of boxes to render
- we map through this `boxes` prop to create child virtual nodes of div elements shaped like a red box containing the text

Comment: How about just a `v-for` over the array? https://jsfiddle.net/bqo515xr/1/

Comment: that was a complex answer for a starter like me. I will learn these concepts thank you! @VamsiKrishna

Comment: @PrasannaSrinivasan i was using so many render functions in my project lately... so that came to me first... but bert's fiddle is the more appropriate one.. :-)

Comment: Even i did the same v-for @Bert Now i'm trying to give input from browser console to the vue script

Comment: Can anyone say how to make the array elements as **id** for the corresponding DOM squares?